# Android UIL use only cached Images

Tags: android, caching, local, offline, universal-image-loader

How to set android UniversalImageLoader to shows only preloaded(no new download) Images.

```
final ImageLoaderConfiguration ilc = new ImageLoaderConfiguration.Builder(context).build();
final DisplayImageOptions.Builder dioBuilder = new DisplayImageOptions.Builder()//
    .resetViewBeforeLoading(true) //
    .delayBeforeLoading(0)//
    .cacheInMemory(true) //
    .cacheOnDisk(true) //
    .imageScaleType(ImageScaleType.EXACTLY) //
    .bitmapConfig(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888) //
    .displayer(new SimpleBitmapDisplayer()) //
    .showImageOnLoading(R.drawable.loading) //
    .showImageForEmptyUri(R.drawable.error) //
    .showImageOnFail(R.drawable.error) //
    .handler(new Handler());
final DisplayImageOptions dio = dioBuilder.build();
final DisplayImageOptions dioLocal = dioBuilder//
    /*maybe something here*/
.build();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By using this [answer's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26738246/android-uil-use-only-chached-images/26740645#26740645) Solution I change my code to:

```
OnlineImageLoader = new ImageLoader() {
    {
        init(imageLoaderConfiguration);
        denyNetworkDownloads(false);
        handleSlowNetwork(true);
    }
};
OfflineImageLoader = new ImageLoader() {
    {
        init(imageLoaderConfiguration);
        denyNetworkDownloads(true);
    }
};
```

And when I want to use **force local works** I use `OfflineImageLoader` else `OnlineImageLoader`

Answer (score 1):

`ImageLoader.getInstance().denyNetworkDownloads(true)`

When you want again to allow to load images from network then call `denyNetworkDownloads(false)`